# Using git push from Qt Creator

Tags: git, qt, github, qt-creator

I want to work with the git tools integrated into Qt. So far I have set up a project and the git repository, and I can commit, status and all others from the IDE and from command line as well. But when I try to use pull or push from the gui it hangs and after 60 seconds gives me this error:

```
The command 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd/git.cmd' did not respond within the timeout limit (60000 ms).
```

When I use the command prompt for `push` or `pull` it prompts me for my ssh passphrase and it works after that.
Is this because the Qt IDE can't display that interactive password input or what else do I need to set up?

I'm using Qt SDK 1.1 and msysgit 1.7.4 and github, and I've installed git with the option to add git executables to my PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed git can't prompt for your passphrase and hangs. The typical work-around is to use key-based ssh authentication. See http://help.github.com/working-with-key-passphrases/ for more details.