# Git timeout on Qt Creator

Tags: git, qt-creator

I am using qt creator and i am unable to push my commits to bitbucket.I can commit from qt creator but not push.I have deone some research and the first place to look was SO and i was fortunate to find this [Using git push from Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699684/using-git-push-from-qt-creator)

However,i have the ssh-agent.exe running and i can commit and push from Git bash on windows.I get this error when i push from qt creator

> The command 'C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.cmd' did not respond within
>   the timeout limit (60000 ms).

Its a known bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-4446 but that was closed in favor of this one https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-2943

My qt creator version is 2.6.2.

is there a solution for this to enable one push from qt creator?.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set credentials permanently, add the following line to **%USERPROFILE%/_netrc** on Windows (or **$HOME/.netrc** on linux):

```
machine site.address.com login <user> password <pass>
```

If you want Qt Creator to prompt you for the password, install ssh-askpass on linux or [win-ssh-askpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winsshaskpass/) on Windows and make sure it is set in Tools -> Options -> Version Control -> General (SSH prompt command).